# Is it a good idea to use lambdas in one function instead of spreading the function across multiple functions?

Tags: c++, function, lambda

Basically, what I mean is this:

```
void funcForFoo1()
{
  // ...
}

void funcForFoo2()
{
  // ...
}

void foo()
{
  // Other two functions will be used here and here only
}
```

VS

```
void foo()
{
  auto lambdaForFoo1 = []()
  {
    // ...
  }
  
  auto lambdaForFoo2 = []()
  {
    // ...
  }
  // Use the lambdas later on
}
```

The lambdas' scope is reduced to only being used inside the function, which is a good thing and possibly an advantage over using other functions. However, I believe lambdas in class functions do not have access to class members unless it captures `this`, and using lambdas as opposed to other functions *may* look just a bit messier compared to using other functions. In your opinion, which one would ultimately be a better choice?

Comment: Note a lambda within a class member function can access other members if it captures `this`.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: For this question to be not opinion based, you'd need to be less abstract without it being too long a question.  Which is a ridiculously narrow eye to thread.

Comment: I disagree this is opinion base. From my observation lambda version of code is harder to read and maintain, it is harder to follow the flow of control (many times I was analyzing fragment of code and suddenly discovered order is different since fragment is actually inside of a lambda). Function version allows you to reuse existing code in more then one function. And there is also a lambda capture which will makes this problems even more frustrating.

Comment: @MarekR "From my observation ... " That just proves it's opinion based. You might find lambdas harder to read. Other might prefer them. Yet others won't care one way or another. This is a recipe to turn this thread into a live debate. That is why the "opinion based" close reason exists.

Comment: @bolov when I see stars on the sky is this also "opinion based"? Should Iwrite about "cyclomatic complexity" of function code which quantifiable?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it depends.

If you want to have access to local function members and easily modify input parameters the lambdas are definitely the far better option. It is great when you debug and adjust the code. But can become a mess if overused.

If you want to reuse the functions (and/or classes) in many places then lambdas are clearly not suitable for the role and functions/classes are the preferred choice.

In your example, it appears that you use them in one function only but neither of them utilize any local variables. So in this particular example it doesn't really matter and more of a style choice. Lambdas have a minor advantage that they don't generate a link symbol that can be corrupted and it also ensures that nobody will use the lambda elsewhere if that's what you want... then again you can make the function static if it is in a .cpp file. One other consideration, is that in function version it is unclear where it is used unless one makes a search but having a large lambda in function is never too pretty either and can easily become a mess.

Comment: Sorry for being so late to my own thread, I had to go to sleep. In my function version, the two functions were to be used _only_ in the last one. My main question was basically the readability of outside functions vs. the lambdas which made more logical sense for me to use due to the reduced scope, but resulted in less readability IMHO.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable these days most editor's can hide lambda/function's intrinsics so they don't occupy space. So the difference in readability is also not significant by any means... unless you randomly sprinkle these definitions throughout the function and make it confusing.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Indeed, when I tried using lambdas in functions, I made sure to put all of them at the top, so I guess you are right in that sense.